# How to connect Django Rest-api with MongoDB?

Tags: django, mongodb

I'm trying to connect Django rest-api with mongo database which i created on mlab.com. Below is my code which I define in settings.py file in my Django rest-api.

```
MONGODB_DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'dummy',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('MONGO_HOST', 
          'mongodb://dummyuser:dummypassword@ds125851.mlab.com:25851/dummy'),
    }
}

mongoengine.connection(
    db='dummy',
    host=os.environ.get('MONGO_HOST', 
       'mongodb://dummyuser:dummypassword@ds125851.mlab.com:25851/dummy'),
)
```

When I run this api I got this error

> host=os.environ.get('MONGO_HOST', 'mongodb://dummyuser:dummypassword@ds125851.mlab.com
>   :25851/dummy'),
>   typeError: 'module' object is not callable

I tried to search for solutions online but I found examples which were for older versions. I'm using Djangorestframework2.0.7, MongoDB3.4 and mongoengine0.15. I couldn't find any answer for this versions. I tried to connect this api to the local database and I got same error. How can I solve it?

Comment: Please add you'r code into code tag. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been successfully connected django rest-api with mongodb. Here is the solution that works for me.

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'dummy',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}

MONGODB_DATABASES = {
    'db': 'dummy',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 27017,
}

Here is the link for more information.
http://blog.tomjohnhall.com/python-3-6-django-2-0-and-mongodb-3-4-3-6/

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps to connect your django 2.0 or more with MongoDB database:

1) Install mongoengine for django 2.0

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine.git#egg=django-mongoengine
```

2)Add these in your settings file:

```
from mongoengine import *

'django_mongoengine', // Add this line to installed app

MONGODB_DATABASES = {
"default": {
"name": '<db_name>',
"host": 'localhost',
"password": '',
"username": '',
"tz_aware": True, # if you using timezones in django (USE_TZ = True)
},
}
```

You can find the details for querying the database [here](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html)

Comment: this is what i had, when i imported mongoengine, `ImportError: cannot import name 'abc' from 'bson.py3compat'`