# How to connect MLAB mongodb from django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

hi i am using below setting but it is not working

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mongodb://username:password@ds249605.mlab.com:49605',
        'NAME': 'mlab1',
    }
}
```

getting an error like

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mongodb://username:password@ds249605.mlab.com:49605' isn't an available database backend.
    Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
        'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'

Comment: try ref to another similar question [How to connect Django Rest-api with MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51355570/how-to-connect-django-rest-api-with-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
     'ENGINE': 'djongo',
     'NAME': 'mlab1',
     'HOST' : 'mongodb://username:password@ds249605.mlab.com:49605/mlab1',     
     'USER' : '*******',       
     'PASSWORD' : '*******',
  }
}
```

pip install djongo

That works for me in such a way